# XML request message over TCP socket in Python

Tags: python, xml, sockets, tcp

I am trying to send a raw XML request to the server over TCP but the server is not responding in response and I have waited for a quite long time for the server. To me, it seems like I am doing a mistake in formatting the XML structure. Could you please help me out? I have attached my code. Requests and replies must end by
[CR/LF] (0x0D followed by 0x0A)

```
import socket
import sys
import time
TCP_IP = '127.0.0.1'
TCP_PORT = 4001
comand  = '''

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<message>

<Request Cmd="GetVersion" />[CR/LF]
 </message>
'''
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) # TCP
sock.connect((TCP_IP, TCP_PORT))
sock.sendall(b'comand')
time.sleep(1)
data = sock.recv(1024)
print (data.decode("utf-8"))
sock.close()
```

Comment: Make sure the server is up and running using Ping.

Comment: The server is responding to the telnet command but It's not responding to the TCP sender.